# Typescript - get array that satisfy a condition

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, angular6

Is it possible to get an output array from the given that contains roles=1 without duplicate ? 
Iam using angular 6 typescript. Is there any typescript array processing functions to do this operation
  //Input Array

```
export const userMenus = [
{
    name: 'Dashboard',
    url: '/dashboards',
    icon: 'icon-speedometer',
    roles:'1,3,4'
},
  {
    name: 'Users',
    url: '/Users',
    icon: 'icon-bell',
    roles:'1,2,3,4'
  },
  {
    name: 'Article',
    url: '/Users',
    icon: 'icon-bell',
    roles:'1,2,3,4',
    children: [
             {
              name: 'Cards',
               url: '/base/cards',
               icon: 'icon-puzzle',
               roles:'1,3,4',
             },
             {
               name: 'Carousels',
               url: '/base/carousels',
               icon: 'icon-puzzle',
               roles:'2,4',
             },
             {
               name: 'Collapses',
               url: '/base/collapses',
               icon: 'icon-puzzle',
               roles:'4'
             }
            ]      
  }
```

]

--Need Output if role is 2. 
removed items that not contain 2 in the role field

```
userMenus = [
  {
    name: 'Users',
    url: '/Users',
    icon: 'icon-bell',
    roles:'1,2,3,4'
  },
  {
    name: 'Article',
    url: '/Users',
    icon: 'icon-bell',
    roles:'1,2,3,4',
    children: [
             {
               name: 'Carousels',
               url: '/base/carousels',
               icon: 'icon-puzzle',
               roles:'2,4',
             },
            ]      
  }
```

Comment: have you try .filter(role === '1') on your array ?

Comment: const filteredUserMenus = userMenus.filter((userMenu) => {
  return userMenu.roles === '2';
});
this worked , but my array has field comes like roles:'1,2' so cant find in it :(

Comment: So just make `roles` and array instead of a string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must filter your array and verify that you have 2 in your roles :

```
const filteredUserMenus = userMenus.filter((userMenu) => {
  return userMenu.roles.find((role) => role === '2');
});
```

short syntax :

```
const filteredUserMenus = userMenus.filter((userMenu) => 
  userMenu.roles.find((role) => role === '2'));
```

EDIT : your data structure is bad, roles shouldn't be a string but an array of role. Anyway, if you can't change it, here is a solution :

```
const filteredUserMenus = userMenus.filter((userMenu) => {
  return userMenu.roles.split(',').find((role) => role === '2');
});
```

short syntax :

```
const filteredUserMenus = userMenus.filter((userMenu) =>
   userMenu.roles.split(',').find((role) => role === '2'));
```

Comment: thanks for the response Florian,

const filteredUserMenus = userMenus.filter((userMenu) => {
  return userMenu.roles.find(2);
});

will get error -- [ts] Property 'find' does not exist on type 'string'. 


const filteredUserMenus = userMenus.filter((userMenu) => {
  return userMenu.roles === '2';
});
this worked , but my array has field comes like roles:'1,2' so cant find in it  :(

Comment: @Vishnudas : i have updated the answer. Please note that your data structure shouldn't be a string, but an array of string. If you can, you should change the structure, else, use the edited solution